Multiple localhost SSL certificates and expiration for Windows .Net web apps
Trying to resurrect an IIS hosted ASP.NET MVC web app where its SSL certificate has expired, and cant seem to find any concise answers to the following questions about certificates under the Trusted Root...->Certificates...
Q1: when a certificate Expiration Date has passed is it no longer usable and might as well be deleted? (reason I ask is I am seeing on (newer) Windows servers multiple Trusted certs with expiration dates going back as far as 1999 ... and posts saying to delete expired ones)

Q2: an expired certificate can't be extended, you always have to create a new one?
Q3: on one server I found has 4 'localhost' certificates, 2 expired, 2 not. How can I determine which certificate each .NET app is trying to use if there are multiple certificates with the same name? Isn't it just simply the name matching the 'SSL URL' project property in VS?

Q4: wouldn't you only have just 1 self-signed 'localhost' certificate to cover all .net web apps, whether .NET framework or .NET Core? Is there a difference? (trying to work out why there are multiple localhost certificates)
Q5: shouldn't the SSL certificates 'Intended Purposes' for web apps be 'Client Authentication', not 'Server Authentication'? (why am I seeing mainly 'Server' ones)
Apologies if any turn out to be dumb questions, I have spent quite a bit of time looking for answers myself, and looking to get a better understanding before going further.

You should be interested in where the private keys for those certificates are, as some of them might also be in that server. All those localhost certificates make me think this machine was also used for testing and development.

Every https server needs a certificate with server authentication purpose, sk those certs are way more common. Https with client cert auth isn't widely used, only may be in companies often with the client cert on a Smartcard.

Answer-1: When a trusted root certificate is expired, immediately deleting may not be suitable for every case, for example CRL (Certificate Revocation Lists) are valid for a number of days, immediately deleting may cause unexpected 'untrusted root' errors. There are OS based services to take care of updating root certificates such as the following:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-cs/certificate-trust#benefits-of-ctl-updater
Answer-2: Yes, it should be renewed
Answer-3: The application should have a way of binding its services to a unique certificate. Even though they look the same, they have different expiry dates, also thumbprints, serial no. are unique for each certificate.
Answer-4: The reason why multiple certificates exist depends upon the application requirements such as OID field requirement, special security requirement, encryption algorithm differences.
Answer-5: Server authentication refers to the server's TLS certificate being well-known and trusted by the clients connecting to the server. The server does not authorize the clients with the server certificate.
